# How can I view images in forwarded packets on (current) Mac OS X?

Tags: network, macos

How can I view reassembled images on a Mac being used as a router? I'd like to do this as a demonstration of how HTTP doesn't provide privacy.

I've done some research, and on Linux there's a tool called [Driftnet](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~chris/driftnet/) which does this. OS X once had [EtherPeg](http://www.etherpeg.org/) but it's no longer maintained.

**How can I reassemble images in forwarded HTTP traffic?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mitmproxy (http://mitmproxy.org) is a free tool for man-in-the-middling HTTP traffic and can accomplish this in a few ways.

The most straightforward and easy to demonstrate would be to use the web interface (mitmweb) which would allow you to click on individual image requests and see the image in your browser.

Since you're using your host as a router, you'll want to enable packet forwarding in OS X and enable transparent mode in mitmweb (-T) and do some pfctl magic to forward the HTTP traffic to the port mitmproxy is running on.

http://mitmproxy.org/doc/transparent/osx.html

Comment: Hrm, while that's not the approach I was thinking of: Driftnet and etherpeg actually reassemble the images from the wire - there's no reason why simply capturing URLs won't work too. Accepted!